# Not able to integrate function involving scalar product

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, integral-equations

For given $h=0.2,D=1.5$, let $w_{i}(x):=\frac{1}{\pi D}\exp^{-||\frac{x-hi}{\sqrt{D}h}||^{2}}$  where $x\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $i\in I \subset \mathbb{Z}^{2}.$ For $x\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ ,let $v(x):=-x$. Then, The objective is to calculate
$$G(i,j):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\ \langle v(x),\triangledown w_{i}(x)\rangle\ w_{j}(x)\ dx.$$
I have tried to calculate in Mathematica (code attached), but I am getting an error. (Note: In code, I have considered bounded domain $[-4.5,5.5]\times[-4.5,5.5]$. Also, $indSet[[m]]$ and $indSet[[n]]$ corresponds to $j$ and $i$ in $G(i,j).$ )

The Code

```
aah = 1/5;                                                      
aaD = 15/10;
v[x1_, x2_] := {-x1, -x2};
f[n1_, n2_] = Function[{x1, x2}, 1/(Pi* aaD)* Exp[-(Norm[({x1, x2} - {n1, n2}*aah)/(Sqrt[aaD]*aah)])^2]] ;   
L[a_, b_, c_] := Table[{f, g}, {f, Floor[a/aah] - c, Ceiling[b/aah] + c, 1}, {g,Floor[a/aah] - c, Ceiling[b/aah] + c, 1}];
indSet = Flatten[L[0, 1, 2], 1];
cISet = Length[indSet];
IntD[m_, n_] := NIntegrate[((f @@ indSet[[m]])[x1,x2])*((v[x1, x2]).D[(f @@ indSet[[n]])[x1,x2], {{x1, x2}}]), {x1, -4.5, 5.5}, {x2, -4.5, 5.5}];
IntD[26, 28]
```

Comment: Please provide executable  Mathematica code, not an image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `(Norm[({x1, x2} - {n1, n2}*aah)/(Sqrt[aaD]*aah)])^2` by `# . # &[({x1, x2} - {n1, n2}*aah)/(Sqrt[aaD]*aah)]`  in the definition of function `f`, which avoids `Abs[], Abs'[]` in the differentiated expressions.

```
aah = 1/5;
aaD = 15/10;
v[x1_, x2_] := {-x1, -x2};
f[n1_, n2_] = 
  Function[{x1, x2}, 
   1/(Pi*aaD)*
    Exp[- # . # &[({x1, x2} - {n1, n2}*aah)/(Sqrt[aaD]*aah)] ]];
L[a_, b_, c_] := 
  Table[{f, g}, {f, Floor[a/aah] - c, Ceiling[b/aah] + c, 1}, {g, 
    Floor[a/aah] - c, Ceiling[b/aah] + c, 1}];
indSet = Flatten[L[0, 1, 2], 1];
cISet = Length[indSet];
IntD[m_ , n_ ] := 
  NIntegrate[((f @@ indSet[[m]])[x1, x2])*((v[x1, x2]) . 
      D[(f @@ indSet[[n]])[x1, x2], {{x1, x2}}]), {x1, -4.5, 
    5.5}, {x2, -4.5, 5.5}];
IntD[26, 28] (*-0.00484788*)
```